# Daily reputation limit

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

Here's a screenshot of my activity for today:

[image]

I have 17 upvotes that accounted for 170 of my reputation and 4 accepted answers that accounted for 60 which makes a total of 230 reputation which is what is shown. So are the accepted answers no longer invulnerable to the daily reputation cap of 200?

Comment: Nothing has changed here AFAIK. And the tab on the top correctly says 230. Odd

Comment: @Pekka, yes but there were upvotes that didn't generate reputation. Only 170 from upvotes. To be honest it's the first time happening to me so I thought something might have changed and as I don't follow the meta very often chances are I've missed something and that's why I thought I might ask.

Comment: @Darin yeah, but the tab title usually shows the correct reputation, not the theoretical one. That's why it's even weirder. You are 10000% sure there are not items missing in the bottom of the list due to some userscript or something?

Comment: @Pekka, I am 1000% sure. I will update the screen shot. Just a sec.

Comment: @Darin yeah. Hmm. Could it be three upvotes from deleted answers?

Comment: @Pekka, how do upvotes from deleted answers work? To be honest I have no idea if I deleted answers today :-) Is there a way to find out?

Comment: @Darin as far as I know, they still count against the daily rep cap (due to caching/denormalization), but will be recounted later (in the rep recalc). I think what you show would make sense if you had a deleted answer with 3 upvotes. You will get 230 points in the end in the recalc. AFAIK, there is no way to get hold of deleted questions you have answered except going through your own browser history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only explanation I have is that you have three upvotes for an answer that was deleted in the meantime.

Maybe do a [reputation recalc](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and see whether things change.

Comment: Yeap, reputation recalc sorted it out. Just as this is the first time happening to me in two years I thought that there might be something wrong. Thanks @Pekka.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is stated clearly in the FAQ for reputation

> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per
>   user per day, and you can earn a
>   maximum of  200 reputation per day
>   (although accepted answers and bounty
>   awards are immune to this limit).
>   Also, please note that votes for any
>   posts marked "community wiki" do not
>   generate reputation.

(It may have changed since you read it last, but I was just looking at it :)

Comment: I know that but then why did I generate 170 reputation from upvotes instead of 200? You can see that I have upvotes that followed and didn't generate any reputation.

Comment: Oh, I was confused by your description "I have 17 upvotes".  Counting now, I see that you had 19 upvotes at the 4h mark, then another 2 (generating only 10 pts), and then 8 more generating no points.  So you got 200 points from upvotes, and 60 from acceptances.  Does your profile really only show 230 for today?

Comment: Oh, and one of those "3"'s only generated 20 points, not 30 . . . do you have activity from about the same time yesterday that might causing you to hit the 200 point limit multiple times today?